# Is it possible to have a tracked .gitignore AND an untracked .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control

I am collaborating on a project with others, and there is a .gitignore in the root directory which is committed to git.  What if I wanted to make a new file or directory in root that I want git to ignore, but I don't want to put it in the public .gitignore, simply because it only pertains to me.  One example of this is that I often create a "sandbox" directory in my current project so that I can experiment with syntax of certain commands while still being inside the project; however, I have no intention of sharing this with everyone else.

Comment: Use either `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` or `core.excludesfile` to specify local ignores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set an additional gitignore file for the current repository with the `core.excludesfile` config option (as mentioned in the comments):

```
git config core.excludesfile .my_gitignore
```

And add your personal files to this file (as well as "`.my_gitignore`" itself).