# gitignore my windows username

Tags: git, gitignore

My Keil projects often store a `.username` file which I want to ignore using gitignore.

I thought I could do `*.$(echo %username%)` in my `.gitignore`, since `echo %username` will print my name in the regular Windows prompt. I am using git bash, and appearently it cannot fetch these global variables (path, username, appdata etc).

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640160/is-it-possible-to-make-gitignore-changed-according-to-environment-variables), .gitignore files are completely static and cannot use variables at all.

Comment: Instead, you could use [an additional .gitignore file local to your copy of the repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510084/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tracked-gitignore-and-an-untracked-gitignore/26510701#26510701). Every user will have to modify it by hand to add a static `*.username` rule (juste one time) but everyone will have their own (and only their's).

Comment: @Dettorer I upvoted your answer at that thread since this will be my accepted answer. I don't know why people post these as comments.  I hope you can post this as an answer insted, so I can accept that instead of Stony's.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I didn't post it as an answer because I thought it would be duplicating an answer, but I think it is actually a good practice on SO, since your question is not exactly a duplicate of this one. I'll post an answer here but feel free (anyone) to tell me if there is a better practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns written in a `.gitignore` file are completely static, you can't use a language like `shell` to make advanced patterns.

Instead, you could use [an additional .gitignore file local to your copy of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510084/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tracked-gitignore-and-an-untracked-gitignore/26510701#26510701):

```
git config core.excludesfile .my_gitignore
```

This command tells git that there is an extra file in which it should look for file patterns to ignore (here, the file is named `.my_gitignore`).

That is a local configuration, therefore, every user will have to issue the same command and create their `.my_gitignore` file by hand to add a static `*.username` rule, but everyone will have their own (and only theirs).

Comment: If it is a bad practice to duplicate such an answer (see the link in my answer), even if the questions are not strictly speaking duplicates, please tell me and point me to the appropriate flag / better practice. I will edit or delete my answer according to the good practice.

Comment: I don't think it's "bad practice" in this, as you link the answer, it's your answer, and your adding crucial info that links the two questions (i.e. there are no variables, so you need an alternative, which you provide).

Answer (score 0):

Thats not working then your `.gitignore` file is modified and you have to commit them.

The best way is to save that files in a seperate ignored folder. you find a schema to exclude them. For example

```
/user/something/.*
```

But modifying your `.gitignore` is not the right way in that case i think.